# Cannot read data from ServerSocket in Java

Tags: java, sockets

The code below is in server side. It could handle client request and then show the client input in my console.

Yet, the problem appears...

The console shows the string "hello from clientA" successfully. But, I cannot use "if" to analyze this word.

My objective is to show "ok" in console if it is a request from "clientA". To conclude that, the program does not reach "System.out.println("ok")" even though it matches the condition.

Please help me )...(

Thanks.

```
while(true)
  {
     Socket server = null;
     try
     {
        server = serverSocket.accept();
        DataInputStream in =
           new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        obtain=in.readUTF();

        DataOutputStream out =
             new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF("server say hello to you");

        System.out.println(obtain);//the console show "hello from clientA" exactly
        if(obtain=="hello from clientA")
        {
            System.out.println("ok");
        }
        server.close();
     }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
     {
         System.out.println("Again");
         try {
            serverSocket.setSoTimeout(20000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
     }
     catch(Exception b)
     {
         break;
     }
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `==` to compare strings, use `String#equals()` method so

```
if(obtain=="hello from clientA")
```

should be replaced by

```
if("hello from clientA".equals(obtain))
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks to your answer. I have never faced this problem before. Your fast reply solved the problem, where I wasted 6 hours. Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Have fun coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Change that if condition to this :

```
if(obtain.equals("hello from clientA"))
    {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
```

`==` operator is checking the reference of the value and not the actual value. Whereas `String#equals` compare the value of object and return TRUE or FALSE accordingly.